# Button to open next dropdown jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mobile-website

So I am refactoring and redesigning an old application and I have multiple dropdown menus that hold data for people to enter and I would like for there to be a button that when clicked on scrolls to the next one and opens it just to make it easier to get through the form.

My html code looks like this:

```
<?php foreach loop that adds more dropdowns when entered in through a modal when they click new?>

   <button class="tEntry-collapsible-btn tsHeader-collapsible-btn waves-effect" 
    id="testing"
    type="button"
    style="background-color: sienna !important;"></button>

    <div class="tEntry-collapsible-row>
         <div class="tTable-row">
             //content to dropdown
         </div>
    </div>
    ....usually around 10-15 dropdown menus with the collapsible btn
<?php loop++ ?>
```

I added a photo for reference, the dropdown buttons are color coordinated and I added a next button at the bottom (minimal styling) and as of right now when the buttons are clicked it drops down fine but I'd also like a button that when clicked i guess focuses the next one and then opens it just for a smoother experience when working your way down the page.

[image: dropdown menus]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Find the `next` dropdown and scroll to it with `.scrollIntoView()`.

You would just call the function that drops the dropdown on the `next` element.

**Note:** not working well in the snippet... try [my codepen](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/QWLgJYj)

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.next', function() {
    var el = $(this).closest('.dropdown');
    var parent = el.closest('.wrap');
    var next = el.nextAll('.dropdown').first();
    
    // scroll like this
    // parent.animate({
      // scrollTop: next.position().top
    // }, 1000);
    
    // or like this; I prefer this one
    next[0].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
  });

});
```

```css
.wrap {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.something {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="next">next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="next">next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```